# How long do wire transfers take?

Tags: international-transfer, wire-transfer

I have a client in Ireland. She deposited the money on a Thursday afternoon. We are on Monday today and the ammount has not been credited to my account.

How long do these transfers take?
I am a citizen of another European country if that is an issue.

Comment: It depends on the cut-off times. Generally 3-5 business days.

Answer (score 1):

The experience I have with wire transfers is from Australia to the US. These transfers can take up to 5 business dates (i.e. a whole week including the non-business days of the weekend).

I would have thought intra-European transfers would be quicker, given how behind most US (regional) banks are in their electronic transfers.

However, I don't think you should be worried just yet.

Comment: @geof I don't think you should worry yet either, but if you are worried, why not call one (or both) of the financial institutions involved and ask them?